# Flask CSS not found for dynamic routing

Tags: python, flask

- I am using same html file for two routes.

  - Where one route is static and other route is dynamic.
  - Static route loading the page with out any issue, but dynamic route
    shows page not found error while loading css files.

Sample code :

```
WORKFLOW_DIAGRAM = Blueprint('workflow_diagram', __name__)

@WORKFLOW_DIAGRAM.route('/workflow-diagram', methods=['GET'])
def show_workflow():
    return render_template('workflow.html')

@WORKFLOW_DIAGRAM.route('/workflow/<workflow_id>', methods=['GET'])
def show_workflow_with_id(workflow_id):
    return render_template('workflow.html')
```

while hitting first route it fetches css from,

```
assets/a.css
```

while hitting second route it fetches css from,

```
workflow/assets/a.css
```

So how can I change the route to use the path `assets/a.css`

Comment: Please post html code where css file is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can indicate which static files to use by referencing them explicitly in your `layout.html` file via `request.endpoint`.

```
{% if request.endpoint == 'show_workflow_with_id' %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static/assets/', filename='a.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endif %}
```